Parallelization with compile gives an error
I have this uncompiled code with MMA14, win10,64
F[x_, y_] = (IdentityMatrix[
      6]  (Cos[x] + 2  Sin[2  y])) + (KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2],
      IdentityMatrix[3]]);
f1[x_, y_] = D[F[x1, y1], x1] /. {x1 -> x, y1 -> y};
f2[x_, y_] = D[F[x1, y1], y1] /. {x1 -> x, y1 -> y};

MyFun[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Block[{val, fun, order, reslt}, {val, fun} = Eigensystem[F[x, y]];
  order = Ordering[val];
  val = val[[order]];
  fun = fun[[order]];
  reslt = (Sum[
     If[in == jn, 
      0, (((Conjugate[fun[[jn]]] . f1[x, y] . 
           fun[[in]])*(Conjugate[fun[[in]]] . f2[x, y] . 
           fun[[jn]])))], {in, 6}, {jn, 6}]); Im@reslt]

data = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}], 
  1];

   

which runs fine and can use parallelization as follows
ParallelTable[
   Sum[MyFun[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z], {i, 
     Length@data}], {z, -1, 1, 0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming     

To enhance performance, I compiled as
compilfun = 
  func |-> 
   Unevaluated@
     Compile[{x, y}, func[x, y], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
      CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@func;

{cf1, cf2, cF} = compilfun /@ {f1, f2, F};

MyFun1[x_, y_, z_, val_, fun_] := 
 Im@Sum[If[in == jn, 
    0., (Conjugate[fun[[jn]]] . f1[x, y] . fun[[in]]*
      Conjugate[fun[[in]]] . f2[x, y] . fun[[jn]])], {in, 6}, {jn, 6}]

cMyFun = 
  Hold@Compile[{x, y, z, {val, _Real, 1}, {fun, _Complex, 2}}, 
        MyFun1[x, y, z, val, fun], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
        CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@MyFun1 /. {f1 -> cf1, 
      f2 -> cf2} /. Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;

eigen[x_, y_] := 
 Block[{val, fun, order}, {val, fun} = Eigensystem[cF[x, y]];
  order = Ordering[val];
  {val[[order]], fun[[order]]}]

eigenlst = eigen @@@ data // Transpose; // AbsoluteTiming

cReslts = 
  Hold@Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {z, _Real}, {val, _Real, 
         2}, {fun, _Complex, 3}}, 
       Sum[MyFun1[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z, val[[i]], 
         fun[[i]]], {i, Length[data]}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
       RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. MyFun1 -> cMyFun /. 
    Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;      

and now I can use Table on cReslts
Table[cReslts[data, z, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]], {z, -1, 1, 
    0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming       

but for large points for z it would be better if I could use ParallelTable as
ParallelTable[
   cReslts[data, z, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]], {z, -1, 1, 
    0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming      

but it gives this error
LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\14.0\WolframKernel" -noicon -noinit -subkernel -wstp,1048,19].


Try to run DistributeDefinitions[cReslts] before the ParallelTable.

@HenrikSchumacher, does not help, the error is still there. By the way, did you reproduce the same error?

From this post, to do parallel calculation with compiled shared libraries, we need to create their copies for each kernel by ParallelEvaluate:
F[x_, y_] = (IdentityMatrix[
      6]  (Cos[x] + 2  Sin[2  y])) + (KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[2],
      IdentityMatrix[3]]);
f1[x_, y_] = D[F[x1, y1], x1] /. {x1 -> x, y1 -> y};
f2[x_, y_] = D[F[x1, y1], y1] /. {x1 -> x, y1 -> y};

MyFun[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Block[{val, fun, order, reslt}, {val, fun} = Eigensystem[F[x, y]];
  order = Ordering[val];
  val = val[[order]];
  fun = fun[[order]];
  reslt = (Sum[
     If[in == jn, 
      0, (((Conjugate[fun[[jn]]] . f1[x, y] . 
           fun[[in]])*(Conjugate[fun[[in]]] . f2[x, y] . 
           fun[[jn]])))], {in, 6}, {jn, 6}]); Im@reslt]

data = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}], 
  1];



ParallelEvaluate[
 compilfun = 
   func |-> 
    Unevaluated@
      Compile[{x, y}, func[x, y], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
       CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@func;
  
  {cf1, cf2, cF} = compilfun /@ {f1, f2, F};
  
  MyFun1[x_, y_, z_, val_, fun_] := 
   Im@Sum[If[in == jn, 
      0., (Conjugate[fun[[jn]]] . f1[x, y] . fun[[in]]*
        Conjugate[fun[[in]]] . f2[x, y] . fun[[jn]])], {in, 6}, {jn, 
      6}];
  
  cMyFun = 
   Hold@Compile[{x, y, z, {val, _Real, 1}, {fun, _Complex, 2}}, 
         MyFun1[x, y, z, val, fun], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
         CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@MyFun1 /. {f1 -> cf1,
        f2 -> cf2} /. Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;
  
  eigen[x_, y_] := 
   Block[{val, fun, order}, {val, fun} = Eigensystem[cF[x, y]];
    order = Ordering[val];
    {val[[order]], fun[[order]]}];
  
  eigenlst = eigen @@@ data // Transpose; // AbsoluteTiming;
 
 cReslts = 
  Hold@Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {z, _Real}, {val, _Real, 
         2}, {fun, _Complex, 3}}, 
       Sum[MyFun1[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z, val[[i]], 
         fun[[i]]], {i, Length[data]}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
       RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. MyFun1 -> cMyFun /. 
    Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;]

Now ParallelTable works:
(test1 = 
    ParallelTable[
     cReslts[data, z, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]], {z, -1, 1, 
      0.1}]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.099441, Null}*)

(test2 = 
    Table[cReslts[data, z, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]], {z, -1, 1, 
      0.1}]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.538477, Null}*)

test1 == test2
(*True*)

Update: another way to do the parallel calculation
To do the parallel calculation with Compile, another way is use the option RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable} and Parallelization -> True. But in this way, you need to specify the dimensions of the input, like {{data, _Real, 2}, {z, _Real}, {val, _Real, 2}, {fun, _Complex, 3}}. Here are the codes:
cReslts1 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {z, _Real}, {val, _Real, 
        2}, {fun, _Complex, 3}}, 
      Sum[MyFun1[data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]], z, val[[i]], 
        fun[[i]]], {i, Length[data]}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
      Parallelization -> True] /. MyFun1 -> cMyFun /. 
   Part -> Compile`GetElement // ReleaseHold;


and the test:
(test1 = 
    ParallelTable[
     cReslts[data, z, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]], {z, -1, 1, 
      0.01}]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.772285, Null}*)

(test2 = 
    Table[cReslts[data, z, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]], {z, -1, 1, 
      0.01}]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*{4.76341, Null}*)

(test3 = 
    cReslts1[data, Range[-1, 1, 0.01], eigenlst[[1]], 
     eigenlst[[2]]]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.0472, Null}*)

test1 == test2 == test3
(*True*)

The reason why test3 runs slower than test2 is that my computer's chip is M3 Pro, with 6 efficiency cores and 5 performance cores. It seems that Parallel* will launch 11 kernels, but cReslts1 runs on only one WolframKernel with multiple threads, and only performance cores are used in the calculation. I don't know how to specify the number of threads to let the left efficiency cores get used, but I think this question disappears on Intel chips and thus cReslts1 will get better performance.
Update: specify the number of threads for cReslts1
The threads can be specified by the system option "ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" from the documentation. By setting
SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 11]

and run the tests again, we get
(test1 = 
    ParallelTable[
     cReslts[data, z, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]], {z, -1, 1, 
      0.002}]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*{3.70789, Null}*)

(test2 = 
    Table[cReslts[data, z, eigenlst[[1]], eigenlst[[2]]], {z, -1, 1, 
      0.002}]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*{23.8647, Null}*)

(test3 = 
    cReslts1[data, Range[-1, 1, 0.002], eigenlst[[1]], 
     eigenlst[[2]]]); // AbsoluteTiming
(*{3.61492, Null}*)

a bit faster than Paralleltable.

,Thanks for the detailed answer!
